# Passbook and iCloud - are multiple registrations triggered upon synching?

Tags: ios, device, registration, icloud, passbook

Assume a user has two iOS devices that support Passbook and that the user has both registered on the same iCloud account, and has Passbook toggled on for synching with iCloud.

If a user downloads an updateable pass (e.g. has webservice URL) through an app (via link) and installs the pass on device A, will device B go through the motions of registering the Passbook pass using the registration service/get serial number/get updated pass?  E.g. from a different POV, must the server assume that the user can synch their updateable pass across different devices, and must it support multiple registrations of the same pass across different devices?

### Background:

Our business wants to use passbook, and we naively thought we could use the device lib identifier to distinguish a device.  Turns out that within a single update (manual or automatic update) the same pass (e.g. passTypeID+serial combo) can change device library identifer as part of their call to the registration REST service.  So we thought we could at least handle this by always updating the most current registration entry with new details so we would at most have one registration.

This breaks if two or more devices can be synched and both automatically go through their own registration processes.  Only one of the devices would have it's pass registered correctly, and it would be difficult to predict which device has a correctly registered pass.  If this doesn't happen, we can hobble along with our current solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented a Passbook Plaform, and we support multiple devices for each Coupon, here is my example with my Mac, iPhone 5 and iPod.

1. I download the coupon from the Mac from the URL eg: https://passqlub.com:8443/passGen/Pass.seam?passId=71
2. Then I have the preview of the coupon and then I click to "Add to Passbook"
3. Like in 5-10 mins, the iCloud of both devices (iPhone and iPod) sync the coupon in both device. As soon as the coupon is downloaded to the Device, it get registered with to records (same serial, same PassType, but two deviceId and tokens)
4. If the platform want to send an update, it must get the serial and passtype and iterate over the devices and send the push notifications.

Hope it helps to clarify the sync of passbook on multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that it is not possible to use the device identifier to distinguish a user or a device.  There are two reasons for this, firstly if a user has multiple devices and an iCloud account then the pass will automatically sync across all devices, and all devices will register with a unique device identifier.

Secondly, for security purposes, devices rotate their identifiers and tokens.  When this occurs, the device re-registers with a new device identifier.  Annoyingly, it does not deregister the old identifier.  The only way you discover that a device identifier is stale is via the APNS feedback service.  So if you are not regularly pushing updates to the pass, or you are not frequently checking the APNS feedback service, you will continue to accumulate device identifier records, when in reality the number of devices has not increased.

The only reliable way to uniquely target a pass is via a combination of `serialNumber`, `authorizationToken` and `passTypeIdentifier`.  These three (or a combination of `passTypeIdentifier` and either of the other two), can act as a reliable primary key.

You might perhaps want to reconsider your schema and logic for targeting records.  Apple's [sample Passbook Server code](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=passbook#) contains a simple but effective SQLite schema for pass records and device records.  In this example, device records are indexed by a concatenation of device identifier and serial number.

In any event, you should be considering your pass records independent to your device records.  When you wish to update a pass, update the pass record, then identify the devices on which the pass is installed, retrieve their device tokens and send to the APNS server.  When each device calls in to retrieve the update, you can always identify the pass record using a combination of `serialNumber`, `authorizationToken` and `passTypeIdentifier`.